# using cd command with a variable

Tags: bash, cd-command

Edit : actually as @thrig says both ways do work.
Mods feel free to delete this question (I can't because it has answers)

I have a folder that I want to `cd` into.
for example, suppose I am in `/home/yannick` and I want to `cd` into `my_folder`.

Now my problem is when the name of the folder is in a variable.
This doesn't work :

```
#doesn't work
my_var=myfolder
cd $my_var
```

But this does :

```
#ok
my_var="myfolder"
cd $my_var
```

Why is that ?
Is there a better way to do it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both of your examples, as shown, are correct. Please update your question with new information (e.g. are those actually the exact directory names being used?) or provide evidence for the "doesn't work" claim.

```
bash-4.1$ mkdir my_folder
bash-4.1$ my_var=my_folder
bash-4.1$ cd $my_var
bash-4.1$ pwd
/home/jdoe/my_folder
bash-4.1$ cd ..
bash-4.1$ my_var="my_folder"
bash-4.1$ cd $my_var
bash-4.1$ pwd
/home/jdoe/my_folder
bash-4.1$
```

Comment: You're right. Hope you won't mind if I delete the question instead of giving you some points you deserved...